# Name email attachment in Google Apps Script

Tags: email, pdf, google-apps-script, pdf-generation, attachment

I have the following G.A.S script to email a google sheet as a pdf attachment.

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var subject = spreadsheet.getRange("U1:U1").getValues();
  var emailTo = spreadsheet.getRange("V1:V1").getValues();
  var message = spreadsheet.getRange("W1:W1").getValues();
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:subject,content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach]});
```

The above code works well except that the file attached to the email message has a bizarre name like "[Ljava.lang.Object_@4e63998c" with no ".pdf" extension!
I am looking for a way to set a name for the pdf file before being attached to the email. The file name should equal the "subject" variable.

Thanks in advance.
Omid

Comment: Try as `getBlob` instead of `getBytes` ?

Comment: @tehhowch TypeError: Cannot find function getBlob in object Blob.

Comment: @omid use it without calling `getBytes()`

Comment: Dear @Tanaike, That was a great help and worked. Check your answer's comments for more detail. However, I still don't understand what does that small `[0][0]` do in the code. Could you please let me know about a page or link to learn about the use of this `[0][0]`? Thanks a lot pal. Take care :)

Comment: @Tanaike BTW, is there any way I can send this pdf file to a specific person through Telegram instead of Email!?

Comment: @tehhowch When I drop `getBytes()`, I get this error message "Attachment content not recognized as string or binary."

Comment: I thought that @tehhowch might propose to modify from ``var pdf = ...`` and ``var attach = ...`` in your script to ``var attach = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).getBlob().setName(subject[0][0]);``. To tehhowch. If I misunderstand your comment, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values retrieved by `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array. I think that the filename becomes such string because the array is used as the filename. Please retrieve the element from the array and try again. So could you please modify as follows?

#### From :

```
var attach = {fileName:subject,content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
```

#### To :

```
var attach = {fileName:subject[0][0],content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
```

You can also use the following modification. In this case, `getValue()` can retrieve the value as a string from the cell "U1".

#### From :

```
var subject = spreadsheet.getRange("U1:U1").getValues();
```

#### To :

```
var subject = spreadsheet.getRange("U1:U1").getValue();
```

#### Reference :

- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to think of other solutions.

Comment: Wow! Great! It solved the issue when I inserted `[0][0]`. However, changing `getValues()` to `getValue()` resulted in a file name consisting of only one character which was the first character of the specified variable's value. BTW, thanks a lot. Bravo :)

Comment: I also appreciate your clear and detailed answer that was completely useful to a novice like me and I could easily apply that. Thanks a lot pal :)

Comment: BTW, is there any way I can send this pdf file to a specific person through Telegram instead of Email!?

Comment: And one more question. The pdf file which is attached includes about 13 pages but only the first couple of pages contain information and the other pages are blank. Is there a way to limit the pdf file only to the part of the sheet that contains data and trim the blank pages?!

Comment: @Omid Thank you for your response. ``[0][0]`` of ``subject[0][0]`` means the address of the element in the 2 dimensional array retrieved by ``getValues()``. In your case, the value from "U1:U1" is only one. So the address is ``[0][0]``. You can see the detail information at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks for your reply and useful explanation. But you forgot to include the link to detailed information. :)

Comment: @Omid I'm sorry. I added the URL. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Omid I'm sorry for my poor English skill. About your additional questions, could you please post it including the detail information as a new question? Because I couldn't understand your situation from your comments. If you posted it as a new question, I think that it will help many users including me think of your solution.

Comment: Thanks I got the link :)

Comment: Actually your English is very good. OK I will post it as a new question. Cheers.

Comment: @Omid Thank you for quick reply. Also I would like to confirm about your post.

Comment: Dear @Tanaike I posted my question as a new post here https://stackoverflow.com/q/50941647/9863856

Comment: @Omid Thank you for letting me know it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but another way to solve this problem might be:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var subject = spreadsheet.getRange("U1:U1").getValues();
var emailTo = spreadsheet.getRange("V1:V1").getValues();
var message = spreadsheet.getRange("W1:W1").getValues();

var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId())
                  .getAs('application/pdf')
                  .getBlob()
                  .setName(subject);

MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[pdf]});
```

The Blob class has a `setName` method https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setName(String), that can be chained into a Blob object (which is the result of `getBlob()`)

After that you just need to add the Blob object inside `attachments` array of function `MailApp.sendEmail`